# How to validate unique id's in two columns in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know that to prevent this from happening:

user_id: 10 | friend_id: 20

user_id: 10 | friend_id: 20

You can use

```
validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :friend_id}
```

But what if you want to prevent a user from adding himself as a his own friend?

user_id: 10 | friend_id: 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You're ensuring that friend_id can't equal user_id

```
validates :friend_id, exclusion: {in: ->(u) { [u.user_id] }}
```