# How to prevent creating the instance of the class with specific IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 Models: Post, User. The User cannot like his post, so how  can i prevent creating the instance of the Model Like (user_id: creator, post_id:created by the "creator") ?

Comment: Just check whether used_id and post_id are the same when you try to create the model, and generate an error if they are?

Comment: where do i do this action ? making a method in my model file ?

Comment: Never override the initialize method in a rails model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate that in your `Like` model:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :post_id
  validate :voter_not_author

  private

  def voter_not_author
    if self.user_id == self.post.try(:user_id)
      self.errors[:base] << "Author can't be the voter"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Another implementation I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698881/how-to-validate-unique-ids-in-two-columns-in-rails)...

```
#app/models/like.rb
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :user_id, exclusion: {in: ->(u) { [Post.find(u.post_id).user_id] }} #-> user_id cannot equal post.user_id
end
```

If you wanted to get rid of the db query, you'd have to associate the models and use `inverse_of`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :likes
end

#app/models/like.rb
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :likes

   validates :user_id, exclusion: {in: ->(u) { u.post.user_id }}
end

#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :likes, inverse_of: :post
end
```